# Parsing the map file?

Tags: c++

I am looking to use the map file to resolve addresses that I get from the exe. Is there a library for parsing it or a more easier to parse format?

Comment: Can you clarify your question?  What kind of addresses, and where are you getting this map file from?

Comment: huh?  Map file?  As in a shapefile?  A raster?  Some other "map" entity?  Can you clarify?

Comment: The map file generated when compiling with /MAP

Comment: I googled compile and /MAP but only found counterstrike references.  Is this what you're talking about and if so, you're in the wrong forum.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAP_%28file_format%29

Comment: Here is an example of a map file generated when linking
http://pastebin.com/d42aaf769

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primary issue is that the format of map files varies with compiler vendors and there are too many compiler vendors out there for us to guess which one you are using.  BTW, there is no standard format for map files; as there is no requirement for one.

I look at the layout of the map file and write my own search programs using `awk`, Perl, Java, C, or whatever is handy and quick (or a language I want to learn).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are talking about map files from MSVC compiler, check the documentation, it should be easy to parse line-by-line:

[basic file format documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7xkk3e2%28VS.80%29.aspx)

There is python code to parse map files programmatically, check this one:

[python map parser](http://www.language-binding.net/pygccxml/apidocs/binary_parsers.html)